# From Angular Actual parameter value is "Ébénisterie" but in JAVA getting value "Ã?bÃ©nisterie"

Tags: java, angular, encoding, decoding

From Angular, there is one parameter and the value of that parameter is Ébénisterie but when I print the value of that variable in java then I got Ã?bÃ©nisterie can you please let me know how I can convert it to original text Ébénisterie? Which Encode/decode I have to apply?

I have tried the following thing.

```
new String(readable.getBytes("ISO-8859-15"), "UTF-8");
new String(readable.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-15");
```

but it's not working.

```
String readable ="Ã?bÃ©nisterie Distinction";
String test = null;
    try {
         test = new String(readable.getBytes("ISO-8859-15"), "UTF-8");
         System.out.println("test"+test);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

    }
```

Expected: Ébénisterie
Actual: Ã?bÃ©nisterie

Comment: You cannot "convert" between these values. You need the original text. The `?` in the String means that you lost data. Why do you use 2 different encodings at all?

Comment: Most probably, your output terminal is simply inaccurately displaying the characters and they're fine in memory.

Comment: @f1sh How we can deal with "Éé" characters there should be some way right and I have tried with different encoding but its not giving proper output

Comment: @chrylis then How I can get the actual value from memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research didn't find anything.

So got one solution in mind that **BASE64 Encode decode** so now from Angularjs sending encoded text and In java side, I have decoded the text.

Here, is the sample code

Angularjs

```
window.btoa("Ébénisterie")
```

JAVA

```
String actualString= new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode("ENCODED STRING"));
```